# Is there a way to make all overlays unlocked immediately?

Tags: cities-skylines

It would be great to be able to view resources and some other overlays immediately to get to grips with road/highway/zone placement instead of having to wait for the game to unlock them for you.

Is there a way to unlock all overlays without unlocking everything else within the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this mod: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=409809475

It unlocks the overlays - but none of the other unlockables.

Answer (score 4):

With an unmodded game? **No**

With mods? **Yes** sure, you can just use the "unlock everything" mod they allready provide with the game.

But note that this disables achievments. There is/was a mod to enable them again, but at the moment it is not conclusive if it still works. Just search the steam workshop for ["enable achievments"](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=407055819)

Comment: Note that there is also a mod that enables achievmets again when playing with mods.

Comment: @gruntswilldie last i know they disabled that mod

Comment: Really? I did not know that,haven't played for some days though.

Comment: @gruntswilldie Thats the last i heard. Went to the steam workshop and the comments are not conclusive, some say it works, but most recent suggest it doesn't, i'll added it to the answer for completness sake

Comment: the enabling archievments mod isn't working anymore. the devs dont want that mod in the game so they implemented a archievement protection

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Either enable the mod that unlocks everything (programmed by the developer itself), or you could use the following mod, which unlocks all basic roads from the very beginning. Just subscribe to it in the Steam workshop, let it install, enable it in the Cities Skylines Mod configurator and enjoy your new Cities experience!

[image: Workshop screencap]

[All basic unlocks at the start](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/407162294)

Please remember that enabling mods disables you ability to obtain achievements. However there is no shame in playing with mods.

Comment: There were some grammar mistakes in your question, already fixed them, you know, you could use your browser auto-correct.

Comment: thanks.  Yea i approved the edit but you did also changed the name of the displayed mod which i rerolled ;)